# DaCe build files

Tags: performance, portability, dataflow

I am using the DaCe framework in Python and would like to generate SDFGs that take command line arguments. I like the sample file DaCe offers and would like to use it as a base for this. However, arguments of the SDFG are defined at the start of the sample file and overwrites any command-line inputs.

Is there any way I could tell DaCe to make an exception and not redefine those variables when creating the sample file?